# Grails domain objects in java used outside of a Grails application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Im trying to access a list of gorm domain objects in a java method but im getting this

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.app.Subscription] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.*

I have a java class im loading as a Spring bean which has an initialise method called on creation.  The java bean is getting created and the grails service injected and it works if i return [new Subscription()] but not if i call Subscription.findAll().  I have followed the wiki and put the classes in packages etc. and have tried different hibernate version etc as other searches for that error state.  Is what im trying to do possible?

```
// Java class
for(Subscription sub : subscriptionService.listSubscriptions() ) {
    subscribe(sub);
}
```

the SubscriptionService class:

```
// Grails service
def List<Subscription> listSubscriptins() {
    Subscription.findAll()
}
```

Subscription domain class:

```
class Subscription {

    Long id

    static constraints = {
        id unique: true,  nullable: false
    }

    def String toString() {
        "${id}"
    }
}
```

Comment: If I let grails autowire a java class into a controller I can directly call Foo.findAll() or indirectly through service (grails 2.4.2). How do you get/use the java class? Does it get autowired? Where?

Comment: I have the grails service class being autowired into the Java class (which is also a bean instantiated using resources.xml).  When debugging through the code i can see the grails service has been injected ok and when i return a plain list from the service method it works.  Only seems to break when the service method calls findAll().  Also using 2.4.2

Comment: Bumping this.  Ive stripped it down to bare basics and still getting the same.  I created a new app in Eclipse called GrailsTester.  Added a domain object called com.test.Sample with no fields.  Created a service called com.test.SampleService and put 

static lazyInit = false
@PostConstruct
def serviceMethod() {
    println 'Here: ' + Sample.list()
}

in it.  Started the app and get the same error.  What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: OK so when i inject the java service into bootstrap.groovy and call from there it works, when i call from a controller it works.  Only seems to not work when calling from an initialise method i.e. with @PostConstruct or setting a bean.initMethod.  Presumably something to do with not everything being up yet im guessing.  Either way ill work round it by using bootstrap.groovy but not ideal as means adding code where config should have sufficed but it is what it is. :-(